# Fastests way to empty a dictionary into an Excel sheet

Tags: vba, optimization, excel, dictionary

What is the fastest way to empty a `Scripting.Dictionary` into an excel sheet? This is what I'm doing right now, but for a dictionary with about 3000 elements, it's noticeably slow. I've made every optimization I can think of.

Here's a bare-bones version of what I have:

```vb
'wordCount and emailCount are late bound "Scripting.Dictionary" objects
Private Sub DictionaryToExcel(ByRef wordCount As Object, emailCount As Object)
    oExcel.EnableEvents = False
    oExcel.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set oWorkbook = oExcel.Workbooks.Add
    oExcel.Calculation = -4135
    With oWorkbook.Sheets(1)
        iRow = 1
        For Each strKey In wordCount.Keys()
            iWordCount = wordCount.Item(strKey)
            iEmailCount = emailCount.Item(strKey)
            If iWordCount > 2 And iEmailCount > 1 Then
                .Cells(iRow, 1) = strKey
                .Cells(iRow, 2) = iEmailCount
                .Cells(iRow, 3) = iWordCount
                iRow = iRow + 1
            End If
        Next strKey
    End With
    oExcel.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Here's the full version including every action I'm taking (mostly formatting, but with one relatively expensive action of doing a spell check on the `strKey` (Although I think this is already optimized as much as it can be:

```vb
'wordCount and emailCount are late bound "Scripting.Dictionary" objects
Private Sub DictionaryToExcel(ByRef wordCount As Object, emailCount As Object)
    Dim oExcel As Object, oWorkbook As Object
    Dim strKey As Variant, iRow As Long
    Dim iWordCount As Long, iEmailCount As Long, spellCheck As Boolean

    Set oExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    oExcel.EnableEvents = False
    oExcel.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set oWorkbook = oExcel.Workbooks.Add
    oExcel.Calculation = -4135
    With oWorkbook.Sheets(1)
        iRow = 1
        .Columns(1).NumberFormat = "@"
        For Each strKey In wordCount.Keys()
            iWordCount = wordCount.Item(strKey)
            iEmailCount = emailCount.Item(strKey)
            spellCheck = False
            If iWordCount > 2 And iEmailCount > 1 Then
                .Cells(iRow, 1) = strKey
                .Cells(iRow, 2) = iEmailCount
                .Cells(iRow, 3) = iWordCount
                spellCheck = oExcel.CheckSpelling(strKey)
                If Not spellCheck Then spellCheck = oExcel.CheckSpelling(StrConv(strKey, vbProperCase))
                .Cells(iRow, 4) = IIf(spellCheck, "Yes", "No")
                iRow = iRow + 1
            End If
        Next strKey

        .Sort.SortFields.Clear
        .Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=.Columns(4), Order:=1
        .Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=.Columns(2), Order:=2
        .Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=.Columns(3), Order:=2
        .Sort.SetRange .Range(.Columns(1), .Columns(4))
        .Sort.Apply

        .Rows(1).Insert
        .Rows(1).Font.Bold = True
        .Cells(1, 1) = "Word"
        .Cells(1, 2) = "Emails Containing"
        .Cells(1, 3) = "Total Occurrences"
        .Cells(1, 4) = "Is a common word?"
        .Range(.Columns(1), .Columns(4)).AutoFit
        If .Columns(1).ColumnWidth > 20 Then .Columns(1).ColumnWidth = 20
        .Range(.Columns(2), .Columns(4)).HorizontalAlignment = -4152
    End With
    oExcel.Visible = True
    oExcel.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

I know there's a really fast method to fire a 2D array into a range of cells, but I'm not sure if there's something similar for Dictionaries.

***edit***

So far, I've made an improvement by adding the values to an array instead of directly to excel cells, and then firing the array to excel:

```vb
Private Sub DictionaryToExcel(ByRef wordCount As Object, emailCount As Object)
    Dim arrPaste() As Variant

    Set oWorkbook = oExcel.Workbooks.Add
    iRow = 1: total = wordCount.count
    ReDim arrPaste(1 To total, 1 To 4)
    For Each strKey In wordCount.Keys()
        iWordCount = wordCount.Item(strKey)
        iEmailCount = emailCount.Item(strKey)
        spellCheck = False
        If iWordCount > 2 And iEmailCount > 1 Then
            arrPaste(iRow, 1) = strKey
            arrPaste(iRow, 2) = iEmailCount
            arrPaste(iRow, 3) = iWordCount
            iRow = iRow + 1
        End If
        count = count + 1
    Next strKey

    With oWorkbook.Sheets(1)
        .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(total, 4)) = arrPaste
```

Comment: Just going out on a limb here, but it can't hurt to try it out pass the dictionaries in to a 2d array and then write the array to the range of cells?

Comment: David Zemens, post an answer this as an answer and you'll get my upvote. I just assumed converting this dictionary to an array in a loop (order N time), followed by the excel push would just take longer, but it wasn't. It was much much faster.

Comment: @DavidZemens Based on your suggestion, I've edited in a modified version which is faster than the original excerpt. Please post your comment as a solution and take some credit!

Comment: glad this worked for you. I have posted an answer!

Comment: Writing to the cell triggers the worksheet calc event ( presumably among other things) which is where the performance gain comes from I think

Comment: @Pynner Disabling Calculation (`oExcel.Calculation = -4135`), application events, and screen updating puts a stop to all that, so there's something more subtle going on here. There's some internal optimization for writing to a range of cells simultaneously that's orders of magnitude more efficient than modifying each cell individually, even in a brand new empty workbook in a hidden excel instance with no calculation tree to update.

Comment: @Alain those are some good points!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try converting the Dictionaries to Array(s) and then transferring the Array(s) to the Worksheet.  The conversion should be relatively quick since it is all in memory.

Then, you should be able to write the array to the worksheet in one action, rather than inside a loop.